# Prestashop: Can't change currency on Currency Block - no cookie?

Tags: cookies, prestashop

Somewhere after my store update to version 1.6.1 (not sure if this is related), I lost the ability to change the currency on the store.

What I already did:

1. Changed theme to default;
2. Disabled overrides;
3. Cleared caches and cookies;
4. Uninstalled/Installed Currency Block.

No results, so far. How far did I get:

1. On setCurrency() call, ajax call is returning 1... so I believe it's working that far.
2. The page is reloading, but the currency remains the same.

What I believe it's happening: Cookie is not being set!

In this function on ChangeCurrencyController.php, I believe something is not working (maybe the line before ajaxDie('1') where cookie is set):

```
public function initContent()
{
    $currency = new Currency((int)Tools::getValue('id_currency'));
    if (Validate::isLoadedObject($currency) && !$currency->deleted)
    {
        $this->context->cookie->id_currency = (int)$currency->id;
        $this->ajaxDie('1');
    }
    $this->ajaxDie('0');
}
```

There's a friend's computer where the cookies weren't cleared since the last updates, where this is working. I believe he has a cookie that is updated on currency change. If I delete his cookies I guess it will stop working. Or is this nonsense?

Can someone give me a hand here?

Can it be something else that has nothing to do with the cookies?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it is not a bug, when you change the currency prestashop change it back based on your browser language. There is an option to turn off in localization > localization > settings > define default country based on browser language > off

Comment: I have the same problem as OP but this method is not working in my case. Ajax is returning "1" as well, so I have no idea what might have gone wrong.